# In NieR Replicant, why don't replicants discover repetition in replicants?

Tags: video-games, clones, nier

As far as I understood, in Nier replicants are special clones, a physical copy of a human but emptied of their soul. They weren't supposed to gain sentience, but accidentally did. As we see in-game, they grow up and grow old like regular humans, but cannot reproduce.

Children are artificially created from genetic data of their "originals" (Gestalts). Overseer androids like Popola and Devola tell a couple they're ready to have a baby, then put them to sleep for a while. When the couple wakes up, they find "their" child next to them.

But this must obviously lead to a constant repetition of the replicants. They live their lives and are later re-created in the image of their originals. While replicants only have access to medieval technology, they could, with paintings (the apothecary mentioned in Kainé's Dreams can paint quite well) and the like, still discover very strong similarities between individuals of some earlier generation and the contemporary generation. So how are they prevented to find out the truth behind the ancient lie?

Comment: Family resemblance is a thing in reality. Any resemblance to a child would just be brushed aside